# Identifier "" not declared in the current scope

Tags: godot

i got this error identifier "GameManager" is not declared in the current scope

```
extends Node2D

class_name Checkpoint

@export var spwanpoint = false

var activated = false


func activate():
    GameManager.current_checkpoint = self
    activated = true
    $AnimationPlayer.play("activated")


func _on_area_2d_area_entered(area):
    if area.get_parent() is Player && !activated:
        activate()
```

Comment: See [singleton(autoload)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html).

Comment: "not declared in the current scope" means `GameManager` is not understood by the compiler in the current context. Some keywords are defined by you, others are defined by the language/framework. Since I don't see `GameManager` defined in the API, I'm assuming it's something you scripted & if that's so, you need to let `Checkpoint` know where/what it is somehow. As per other comment, you may need to use an autoloaded singleton. We can't know for sure because you haven't explained your code.